# Display object in JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array,

```
var test = [{
        id: 0,
        test_id: "Password test",
        pass: 1,
        fail: 5,
        time: 0.03,
        pass_fail: 20,
        comments : [
            {comment : "a comment", commentuser : "user" },
        ]
    };
]
```

within I want to get the value of *comment* and *commentuser* in the object *comments*.
I tried as follows,

```
JSON.stingify(test.comments) // output : "{"comment":"a comment","commentuser":"user"}"
```

Is there a way to just get the value ?
wanted output : "*a comment,user*"

Cheers

Comment: If it is an array with only one element you can just get it as follows: `var comment = test[0].comments[0].comment; var commentuser = test[0].comments[0].commentuser;`

Comment: var output = ${test[0].comments[0].comment},${test[0].comments[0].commentuser} **backticks at the start and end.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the `Object.values` of `test[0].comments[0]` :

```js
var test = [{
  id: 0,
  test_id: "Password test",
  pass: 1,
  fail: 5,
  time: 0.03,
  pass_fail: 20,
  comments: [{
    comment: "a comment",
    commentuser: "user"
  }]
}]

var result = Object.values(test[0].comments[0]).join(',');

console.log(result);
```

Or deep destructure the object you want and join the `Object.values` :

```js
var test = [{
  id: 0,
  test_id: "Password test",
  pass: 1,
  fail: 5,
  time: 0.03,
  pass_fail: 20,
  comments: [{
    comment: "a comment",
    commentuser: "user"
  }]
}]

var [{
  comments: [obj]
}] = test;

var result = Object.values(obj).join(',');

console.log(result);
```